# Putting two figures side by side

Tags: graphics

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Vlieger} 
    \caption{Vlieger}
    \label{fig1:}
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Pijl}
    \caption{Pijl}
    \label{fig2:}
\end{minipage}
```

This is my code to put my two images next to each other. But it doesn't work... Can someone pleas help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. How wide is the text block? You're restricting the `minipage` to have width `0.5\textwidth`, while each graphic is given a width of `3cm`. If `6cm` exceeds `0.5\textwidth`, the two graphics simply won't fit in the available space.

Comment: Incidentally, is the `minipage` embedded in a `figure` environment? The reason I ask is that you're using `\caption` statements, which generally don't work outside of `figure` and `table` environments.

Answer (score 21):

As Mico suggest, probably you want to make a `figure` environment, where you can have two figures with two captions using `minipages` or `subfigures` environments with two subcaptions ans a main caption. Note that figure environments are floats, so by default they can be moved to the top or bottom of the page, or to another page, although you can [influence the position of float environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).

In any case, in these environments and the images usually is better set relative lengths as `\linewidth` instead of absolute lengths as `3cm`.

On the other hand, at least for big images, instead of `\centering` (and some spacer between the `minipages` or the `subfigures`) you may want these aligned with the margins, no matter its exact size. For this, use `\hfill` as in this minimal working example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption} %  for subfigures environments 
\begin{document}
% Side by side subfigures 
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image A}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[h]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image B}
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{This is a figure with two subfigures}
\end{figure}
% Side by side figures 
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Image A}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Image B}
\end{minipage}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For everyone who is coming here and the code isn't working because `subfigures` is outdated: Refer to the last paragraph of this Overleaf help article https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Illegal_unit_of_measure_(pt_inserted)  and replace `\usepackage{subfigures}` by `\usepackage{subcaption}`

Comment: For some reason I get only the caption only for Image B, and it appears under Fig A. Any idea?

Comment: @ScienceFriction With my TeX LIve 2023 updated just now, I still obtain with the MWE as is, the same result that eight years ago, no matter if I use pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex. Therefore no, I no have idea of your problem,  but chances are  that you are not compiling  the MWE as posted here,  or that you have some problem with your LaTeX installation.

Answer (score 0):

@ScienceFriction, I don’t know if it will help, but I noticed that if you want to put image side by side in subfigure environment, you have to add a % symbol just after (in the same line) the first \end{subfigure}. If you delete this symbol, figures (still in subfigure environment) will be placed one below the other.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261278)