# Can't get two figures side by side to work

Tags: subfig, parbox

I have tried quite many methods of getting two figures to compile side by side. Most of these method end up giving this error

```
Emergency stop subcaption.sty 66
```

Which shows this line in the file `subcaption.sty`

```
\subcaption@CheckCompatibility
```

I have tried most of the methods provided in these links:

[Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)

[LaTeX figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37581/latex-figures-side-by-side)

[Putting two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282869/putting-two-figures-side-by-side)

[Side-by-side images in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246537/side-by-side-images-in-latex)

I have tried changing `\usepackage{subfigure}` with `\usepackage{subfig}` I have tried to change the options provided in front of subfigure.

The code for the two figures as it is now:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \parabox{4cm}{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{{ example−image−a}}
    \caption{Fyrir}
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}{4cm}
      \includegraphics[width=4cm]{ example−image−b}
      \caption{Eftir}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Mismunur í afhendingagetu milli 2019 og 2023 \label{fig:afhendingageta}}
     \end{figure}
```

All of the packages (current):

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}} % Add Table of Contents to PDF "bookmark" table of contents
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
```

My LaTeX document is quite massive, so if you want a minimal working document, I'll paste it into pastebin (or similar) and share the link here. If there is a spelling mistake in my code, I am not seeing it.

I am pretty sure all of me system is up to date (on a rolling release Linux).

Comment: Please make a single MWE not sniplets like this and please use images others have access to for example those that come with the `mwe` package https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe?lang=en. In short make a self contained minimal example others can copy and test as is. Then it is a lot easier to test your code and offer help.

Comment: Often in the process of making the example or reducing it to be minimal you will find the source of the problem.

Comment: Working on figuring out how to install the package (and then how to use it).

Comment: Is this the change that needed to happen ( example−image−a and  example−image−b)?

Comment: Yes and then make it a single example. Here there is no document class (in examples you should generally use a standard class) and there is no `\begin/end{document}`

Comment: There are stupid many `renewcommand` in the document. I think it would be better to throw it on pastebin and share it like that.

Comment: BTW looking at your preamble, it is a big mess. `subfigure`, `subfig`, `subcaption` all at the same time. Probably only use the latter. Replace `\usepackage{t1enc}` with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: No, links rot over time and your question will become unusable for others. This is why we ask for a **minimal** example, not your whole document. But fix the packages I mentioned a minute ago

Comment: Additionally, with a few exceptions, `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded (as it has to adjust itself to other packages)

Comment: Well, this came standard from my univercity. I have cleaned some, but being a bit new to latex. So remove `subfigure`, `subfig` and `subcaption` and keep `tlenc` and `T1` ?

Comment: Note that your code example does not even use any subfigures which should be an indicator that something else is going on (aka your messy preamble).

Comment: I did try `bebin{subfigure}` and I got an error, can't remember now it was the same or not.

Comment: Did that entire mess come from your University? Shame on them. You should only use the package y6ou actually need. Also a good idea to add a small comment above each package with a small note as to what they do. Then it is easier to determine if this is something you need

Comment: I probably added `subfig` without noticing the `subfigure` package

Comment: Note that the name you use for the images are not ascii the `–` should be `-`

Comment: I can't see the difference. between these :(
And I am not sure if I use ascii at all...

Comment: Are you on a Mac? It is called `example-image-a` not `example–image–a`, the former is using ascii hyphen the latter is using `–` (or similar) a unicode char for an en-dash.

Comment: I am on Arch Linux, and the dash is the only option I have for my keyboard language. Note though, I copied the names example-image-a from the mwe document found here https://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/mwe/mwe.pdf

Comment: It might be your editor that converts it. I've seen some editors do this on Mac. Arch? Oh boy... Their LaTeX version can be a bit of a mess.

Comment: In any case, your parbox has no closing brace,  You should probably add one after the first \caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just FWI this compiles

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
% \usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage[sf,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[format=plain,labelformat=simple,labelsep=colon]{caption}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\BeforeTOCHead[toc]{\cleardoublepage\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}} % Add Table of Contents to PDF "bookmark" table of contents


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \parbox{4cm}{
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Fyrir}
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}{4cm}
      \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
      \caption{Eftir}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Mismunur í afhendingagetu milli 2019 og 2023 \label{fig:afhendingageta}}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comments

- use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` instead of `t1enc`
- use `enumitem` over `enumerate`
- use `xcolor` over `color`
- I'd probably use `subcaption` instead of the others
- load `hyperref` last
- There were several spelling errors in the code provided.
- Load only packages that you actually need.
- It is good advise to write a small note above each package explaining why it is used. Then if the doc is given to someone else to use as a template they can decide if they need it.

Comment: I do get `Undefined control sequence` in my code. I did copy/paste into my LaTeX from your answer. The reason why the code is a mess, is because the Thesis I am working on HAS to be specifically set up.

Comment: @ÓlafurVíðirGuðbjargarson did you copy the entire thing with no modifications? And exactly which error did you get?

Comment: Found a spelling errror in my code, and the code compiles now..... Now, to have the figures side by side... thanks man. :D, I knew the code I got was bit hot potato, but this bad

Comment: Just a question @daleif can I use `\subfloat` here? I find it somehow more appealing

Comment: Use the syntax you find best, just remember that some packages as not compatible with each other, for example that long list of sub.. stuff.